# Django - Escaping quotes in a template

Tags: html, django

I am trying to create a table that has rows of data that represent Contacts - a mix of people and company contacts. I want each row to be "clickable" so that, when clicked, that contact's form is pulled up for editing. To do that, I have something like this:

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href='{% url my.django.view %}'">...
```

You'll notice that the above has two levels of quotes: a double " after the equals, then a single ' to encapsulate the django template tag. There are two types of contacts: companies and people. I have my `urls.py` set up to handle this, with the following:

```
(r'^contact-details/(?P<cType>C)/(?P<cid>N)/$', contact_details),
(r'^contact-details/(?P<cType>P)/(?P<cid>N)/$', contact_details),
(r'^contact-details/(?P<cType>C)/(?P<cid>.*)/$', contact_details),
(r'^contact-details/(?P<cType>P)/(?P<cid>.*)/$', contact_details),
```

So, with the above, I have two urls for new contacts (distinguished by `cType` of C=Company or `cType` of P=Person) then two more urls for existing contacts (using `cid` for the primary key of the record).

The link imbedded in the rows of the table which list all the contacts looks like this:

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href='{% url cpm.contacts.views.contact_details 'P' c.pk %}'">
```

The problem I am having is that I can't pass in a 'P' or a 'C' into the link, because it would cause a third level of quotes and, thus, break the quotes all together. I just don't know how to escape that third level of quotes, around the P or C.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use double quotes around the "P", because the Django `{%` escape prevents the embedded double quote from closing the quotes for the HTML attribute.

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href='{% url cpm.contacts.views.contact_details "P" c.pk %}'">
```

Comment: Perfect! I did not know that Django had that trick up its sleeve. Thanks for the quick reply, it worked with the double quotes.

Answer (score -2):

maybe just create a simple jQuery / JS method to change window location and put it ina seperate JS file ?

```
function change_location(location){
    window.location = location;
}
```

and use it like:

```
<tr onclick="change_location({% url cpm.contacts.views.contact_details 'P' c.pk %});">
```